# Watching for file changes on complete file transfer

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a simple node script that looks for a file changes and copies file to the remote server using ssh.

```
fs.watch(filename,function(curr,prev){

//copy file to the remote server

});
```

However, since the file i'm watching is uploaded via `ftp` and for every chunk of data i recieve  the file gets changed and the callback gets fired. Is there any way to look for changes only when the complete file has been transfered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but for anyone else in the same situation there is now the below module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/remote-file-watcher

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, you can probably get by with an [inotify binding module](https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify) and the IN_CLOSE_WRITE flag. That event will tell you when a process that previously opened the file for writing has now closed the file descriptor.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I somehow missed the notification for your answer. I'll try this and revert back. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation on a windows platform, and ended up doing this:

```
try {
    var nRetries = 10; 
    var retryTimeInterval = 500
    var currentRetry = 0;
    var pollFunction = function(){
    try{
        var rootFolder = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
        var completePathToFile = path.resolve(rootFolder, filePath);
        fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(rootFolder, filePath));

        // do stuff with file here
    }
    catch(e){
        if (currentRetry < nRetries) {
            currentRetry += 1;
            setTimeout(pollFunction, retryTimeInterval);
        } 
    };
pollFunction();
```

The file must be locked by the ftp server while being written to (So fs.readFileSync throws).

It is not very pretty, but I did not find any other way.