# Wait until file is created to read it in node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to use file creation and deletion as a method of data transfer (not the best way, I know.) between python and nodejs. The python side of the program works fine, as I am quite familiar with python 3, but I can't get the node.js script to work.

I've tried various methods of detecting when a file is created, mainly with the use of `try {} catch {}`, but none of them have worked.

```
function fufillRequest(data) {
  fs.writeFile('Response.txt', data)
}

while(true) {
  try {
    fs.readFile('Request.txt', function(err,data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  } catch {

  }
}
```

The program is supposed to see that the file has been created, read it's contents, delete it and then create and write to a response file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either user a recurring timer or `fs.watch()` to monitor when the file appears.

Here's what it would look like with a recurring timer:

```
const checkTime = 1000;
const fs = require('fs');

function check() {
   setTimeout(() => {
       fs.readFile('Request.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              // got error reading the file, call check() again
              check();
          } else {
              // we have the file contents here, so do something with it
              // can delete the source file too
          }
       });
   }, checkTime)
}

check();
```

Note: Whatever process is creating this file should probably use an exclusive access mode when writing so that you don't create a race condition where it starts reading before the other process is done writing.

Comment: It's working, but returning the data as a buffer with hexidecimals. How to i translate this to plaintext?

Comment: @Anaxion - You can see [the doc for `fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).  If you want the content as a string, then pass the utf8 encoding to [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

Answer (score 3):

@jfriend00 solution is correct. However, In the above solution. It never cleans the timeout. It may cause an issue. If u need blocking code and better timer handling u can use setInterval.

Sample:

```
const checkTime = 1000;
var fs = require("fs");
const messageFile = "test.js";
const timerId = setInterval(() => {
  const isExists = fs.existsSync(messageFile, 'utf8')
  if(isExists) {
    // do something here
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }
}, checkTime)
```

You can also run your python program. No need to write another script.

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const proc = spawn('python',["./watch.py"]);

proc.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()))
proc.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()))
```

Comment: Was going to post an answer closer to this. You don't want to make a recursive call inside the error condition for the readFile function like the other answer. In this case a setTimeout calling a recursive tryReadFile() may work well.

Comment: @adamrights The other answer is OK--since it's async, there's no actual recursion happening so it won't overflow the stack. Also, using `setTimeout` means it'll clean itself up after the last iteration. That said, `setInterval` with a `clearInterval` is generally a bit cleaner for that repeated use case.

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers are a bit old fashioned with async callbacks. Here's a more modern promise-based version tested in Node 18:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const path = require("node:path");
const timers = require("node:timers/promises");

const waitForFile = async (
  filePath,
  {timeout = 30_000, delay = 200} = {}
) => {
  const tid = setTimeout(() => {
    const msg = `Timeout of ${timeout} ms exceeded waiting for ${filePath}`;
    throw Error(msg);
  }, timeout);

  for (;;) {
    try {
      const file = await fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: "utf-8"});
      clearTimeout(tid);
      return file;
    }
    catch (err) {}

    await timers.setTimeout(delay);
  }
};

// test it:
(async () => {
  const file = "test.txt";
  setTimeout(() => fs.writeFile(file, "hello world!"), 3000);
  const content = await waitForFile(file);
  console.log(content);
  await fs.unlink(file);
})();
```

If you want, you can remove `fs.readFile` from the `waitForFile` function if you just want to know it exists or leave responsibility to the caller, rather than automatically read it. In this version, the `for` loop body would look like:

```js
try {
  await fs.stat(filePath);
  clearTimeout(tid);
  return;
}
catch (err) {}
```

Comment: ``Timeout of ${timeout} ms exceeded waiting for ${path}`` is wrong - `path` is defined to be `const path = require("node:path");`. Also this code doesn't handle the case for an "infinite" timeout. And it's not idiomatic to pass a `dir` and a `file` to a function that handles a path. You could pass a path and get the dirname of that path with `path.dirname` if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I changed the variable name in there and forgot to update all usages. I wouldn't use an infinite timeout. If something doesn't work in a day or two, probably best to throw and log the error or retry, although I think passing `Infinity` will achieve your goal with an explicit override. Good point about `path.dirname`. I'll update that.

Comment: `return fs.readFile` can be changed to `return await fs.readFile` too.

Comment: @Marco what's the point of that? If I'm returning a promise, I don't bother `await`ing it, since it just adds an extra promise, although I guess it's more robust to refactoring, if you remove the `return` and forget to add `await` at some point in the future.

Comment: Besides, `(await fs.readdir(dir)).includes(file)` is going to be very slow if `dir` happens to have many files in it. It would be better to skip that entirely and use something like `fs.lstat` or `fs.access`. And to your comment: it's senseless to return a `Promise` from an `async` function. An `async` function is supposed to give you a resolved Promise as a return value. However, this is opinion-based.

Comment: @Marco Not really--`async` functions _always_ return promises. So you can return the promise directly in one step, or resolve it, then re-wrap it in another promise (created by the `async` keyword) that resolves instantly, as you're suggesting. It's basically the same either way, but I find it less typing and clearer to just return the promise, since the `await` keyword is extra. In many cases, I find that the last promise is the only promise I'm using, and I can remove the `async` keyword and simplify further. You're right about speed though, feel free to add a better answer.

Comment: As said, this is just an opinion I have. Sure, technically you can do it. By the way, you still need to define `file` as `const file = path.basename(filePath);`

Comment: All fixed. I got sucked into using `readdir` from another use case where I was matching a partial filename, but forgot I can just use `stat` here. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: You're most welcome :) Ah, I see. Now for that use case `fs.readdir` sounds like a reasonable solution, probably would've done the same for matching partial file names.