# How to wait for a file to exist in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fs, file-exists

In my Node.js application, I need to read from a **log** file which has this two condition:

- **It may not created yet. It is going to be created in some seconds.**
- **It is updating and log lines are added to it for some time. Updates should be sent to client via websocket**

Recieving a request from client, to read this file and send its continuing updates, it may not exsit and throw an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'path/to/file'
```

How can i handle that?

Here is the part of code throw error:

```js
const monitorFile = (ws, path) => {
   let tail = new Tail(path);
   tail.on('line', (data) => {
     ws.send(JSON.stringify({type: 'log', info:data}));
   });
   tail.on('error', (err) => {
     console.log(err);
   });
};

//....
let fileExists = fs.existsSync(logFilePath);
if (fileExists) {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(logFilePath);
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({type: 'log', info:file.toString('utf8')}));
    monitorFile(ws, logFilePath);
}else {
     monitorFile(ws, logFilePath);
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailfd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until file is created to read it in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157254/wait-until-file-is-created-to-read-it-in-node-js)