# Waiting for download to complete on Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a script made using node.js and puppeteer which downloads a file from a button (which doesn't redirect to a url), so right now i'm using await `await page.waitForTimeout(1000);` to wait for the download to complete but it has a few flaws, such as:

Depending on the connection, the download might take more than 1000ms to finish, as well as it might take less, which wouldn't make sense to wait more than what took to finish the download.

My question is, is there a way to wait for a download to complete using Node+Puppeteer? I have tried using `waitUntil: 'networkidle0` and networkidle2 but both seem to wait forever.

Code below:

```
const path = require('path');

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

  /* Initialize some variables */
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

// Instantiates a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage(); 

// Gets current path
  const downloadPath = path.resolve('./'); 

// Specifies wether it allows downloading multiple files or not
  await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', 
  {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: downloadPath}); 

// Goes to My Website
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080/mywebsite');   

// Exports to CSV 
  await page.waitForSelector("#W0009EXPORTAXLS > a > i", {visible: true});
  await page.tap("#W0009EXPORTAXLS > a > i");

  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

// Log
  console.log('File exported.');

// Closes the browser
  await browser.close(); 
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait for all downloads to complete with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471235/how-to-wait-for-all-downloads-to-complete-with-puppeteer)