# Wait for all downloads to complete with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to use the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471235/how-to-wait-for-all-downloads-to-complete-with-puppeteer), but it doesn't work out.

The waitForFunction seems to get skipped and is not evaluated.

chrome://downloads/ is shown, the file still downloads and the script ends.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false, slowMo: 100, // Uncomment to visualize test
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://speed.hetzner.de/');

  // Resize window to 1588 x 901 and await navigation
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1588, height: 901 });

  // Click on <a> "10MB.bin"
  await page.waitForSelector('[href="10GB.bin"]');
  await page.click('[href="10GB.bin"]');

dmPage = await browser.newPage()
await dmPage.goto('chrome://downloads/')


await dmPage.bringToFront()
await dmPage.waitForFunction(() => {
        // monitoring the state of the first download item
        // if finish than return true; if fail click
        const dm = document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot
        const firstItem = dm.querySelector('#frb0')
        if (firstItem) {
            const thatArea = firstItem.shadowRoot.querySelector('.controls')
            const atag = thatArea.querySelector('a')
            if (atag && atag.textContent === 'Show in folder') {
                return true
            }
            const btn = thatArea.querySelector('cr-button')
            if (btn && btn.textContent === 'Retry') {
                btn.click()
            }
        }
    },
    { polling: 'raf', timeout: 0 }, // polling? yes. there is a 'polling: "mutation"' which kind of async
)
console.log('finish')

//   await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: You are setting a timeout of 0. Could you try to increase it or to remove the timeout setting?

Comment: Thanks, tried both - didn't change anything.